# How do could I insert a certain value into a specific column

Tags: python, sql

```
import sqlite3 as db

def criar_grupos():     
    global cursor3,nome_grupo
    nome_grupo = raw_input('name of group')
    nome_criador = raw_input('new user')
    conn3 = db.connect("tabela_grupos.db")
    cursor3 = conn3.cursor()
    cursor3.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groups (name string NOT NULL 
UNIQUE)')
    conn3.commit()

    cursor3.execute("alter table grupos add column '%s' 'string'" % 
nome_grupo)
    cursor3.execute('UPDATE grupos SET ("nome"=?) WHERE name=?', 
(nome_grupo, nome_criador))   

criar_grupos()
```

I'm having a bad time trying to execute this function.

I keep getting the error message:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`

What could I be doing wrong.?

Comment: UPDATE is for editing an existing record. If you want to insert new record use INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: But how do I specify the column that I want to insert the data?

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you are trying to do, honestly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO <table> (col1, col2, col5) VALUES ('val1','val2','val5');
```

Comment: The thing is that I have to specify the column I want to insert "nome_criador" as "nome_grupo". How do I do it?

Comment: Please provide information about how your schema look like. - I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
cursor3.execute('UPDATE grupos SET ("nome"=?) WHERE name=?', (nome_grupo, nome_criador))
```

To this:

```
cursor3.execute('INSERT INTO grupos (?) VALUES (?);', (nome_grupo, nome_criador))
```